# What is the best way to conditionally apply attributes in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to be able to add for example "contenteditable" to elements, based on a boolean variable on scope.

Example use:

```
<h1 attrs="{'contenteditable=\"true\"': editMode}">{{content.title}}</h1>
```

Would result in contenteditable=true being added to the element if `$scope.editMode` was set to `true`.
Is there some easy way to implement this ng-class like attribute behavior? I'm considering writing a directive and sharing if not.

**Edit:** 
I can see that there seems to be some similarities between my proposed attrs directive and [ng-bind-attrs, but it was removed in 1.0.0.rc3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/55027132f3d57e5dcf94683e6e6bd7b0aae0087d#L1L233), why so?

Comment: I haven't come across anything like that.  I vote do it! :D  Maybe submit it to the angular project.  A syntax that better matches the ng-class would be nice. `ng-attr="expression"`.

Comment: I'm definately considering that yes!

Comment: This really isn't the same as ngClass or ngStyle because they control a *single* attribute and you want to control *any* attribute. I think it would be better to create a `contentEditable` directive.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller +1 on that. I think there is a little benefit to be able to control any attribute, especially considering the complexity. You can have directives conditionally acting on a variable.

Comment: `<h1 ng-attr-contenteditable="{{editMode && true : false}}">{{content.title}}</h1>`

Comment: In case you can here looking for Angular 2+ then just do following e.g. <input [readonly]="mode=='VIEW'">

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller: how a directive will conditionally apply? can you explain? and am asking for attribute directive.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

I am using the following to conditionally set the class attr when ng-class can't be used (for example when styling SVG):

```
ng-attr-class="{{someBoolean && 'class-when-true' || 'class-when-false' }}"
```

The same approach should work for other attribute types.

(I think you need to be on latest unstable Angular to use ng-attr-, I'm currently on 1.1.4)

Comment: you can also use this method with things other than booleans, like checking if a variable is set to something certain.
     `code` class="{{varToCheck=='valueToCheck' && 'class-if-true' || 'class-if-false' }}" `code`

Comment: Just to clarify this answer: If you prefix *any* attribute with `ng-attr-`, then the compiler will strip the prefix, and add the attribute with its **value** bound to the result of the **angular expression** from the original attribute value.

Comment: I have published an article on working with Angular+SVG that covers many such issues. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709340/Implementing-a-Flowchart-with-SVG-and-AngularJS

Comment: In my opinion it's easier to read if you use a ternary operator, for which support was added in 1.1.5. That would look like: {{ someConditionalExpression ? 'class-when-true' : 'class-when-false' }}

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the attribute gets created regardless of the outcome. Ideally we'd like control wether or not the attribute gets created at all.

Comment: NOTE: this does not work with directives that are classes, as it doesn't get re-compiled

Comment: Note that the ng-attr- stuff was removed from Angular 1.2. This ansswer is no longer valid.

Comment: You are wrong. This project https://github.com/codecapers/AngularJS-FlowChart uses Angular 1.2 and ng-attr-. Also the latest docs (Angular 1.4) still include ng-attr-

Comment: it works, yeah!!! but is extremely slow. Do not use it for ng-repeat'ed elements!

Comment: Ha, this is probably old advice now. Then it seem the best way to style SVG, but AngularJS may have changed in the meantime! There might be a better way now.

Comment: ng-attr wasn't really removed. It was just refactored. The start of the new implementation is here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/cf17c6af475eace31cf52944afd8e10d3afcf6c0

Comment: Apparently it seems to be bad practice. https://docs.angularjs.org/#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-

Comment: Not working for multiple attribute on select element. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272960/why-ng-attr-cant-be-used-with-attribute-multiple

Answer (score 127):

You can prefix attributes with `ng-attr` to eval an Angular expression. When the result of the expressions undefined this removes the value from the attribute.

```
<a ng-attr-href="{{value || undefined}}">Hello World</a>
```

Will produce (when value is false)

```
<a ng-attr-href="{{value || undefined}}" href>Hello World</a>
```

So don't use `false` because that will produce the word "false" as the value.

```
<a ng-attr-href="{{value || false}}" href="false">Hello World</a>
```

When using this trick in a directive. The attributes for the directive will be false if they are missing a value.

For example, the above would be false.

```
function post($scope, $el, $attr) {
      var url = $attr['href'] || false;
      alert(url === false);
}
```

Comment: I like this answer.  However, I don't think if value is undefined it will  hide the attribute.  I might be missing something, though.  So the first result would be <a ng-attr-href="{{value || undefined}}" href>Hello World</a>

Comment: @RomanK hi, the manual states that `undefined` is a special case. *"When using ngAttr, the allOrNothing flag of $interpolate is used, so if any expression in the interpolated string results in undefined, the attribute is removed and not added to the element."*

Comment: Just a note to aid any future readers, the 'undefined' behaviour appears to have been added in Angular 1.3. I am using 1.2.27 and currently must IE8.

Comment: To confirm some more Angular 1.2.15 will display href even if value is undefined, looks like the undefined behavior starts in Angular 1.3 as the above comment states.

Comment: It's important to note that `ng-attr-foo` will still **always** invoke the `foo` directive if it exists, even `ng-attr-foo` evaluates to `undefined`. [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14575)

Answer (score 99):

I got this working by hard setting the attribute. And controlling the attribute applicability using the boolean value for the attribute.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<div contenteditable="{{ condition ? 'true' : 'false'}}"></div>
```

Comment: As angular can parse the IIF expression this works perfectly for evaluating state in the current scope and assiging values based on that state.

Answer (score 21):

In the latest version of Angular (1.1.5), they have included a conditional directive called `ngIf`.  It is different from `ngShow` and `ngHide` in that the elements aren't hidden, but not included in the DOM at all.  They are very useful for components which are costly to create but aren't used:

```
<h1 ng-if="editMode" contenteditable=true>{{content.title}}</h1>
```

Comment: I believe ng-if only works on an element level, that is, you can't specify a conditional to just one attribute of an element.

Comment: Indeed, but you can then do `<h1 ng-if="editMode" contenteditable="true"><h1 ng-if="!editMode">`

Comment: beware, however, that `ng-if` creates a new scope.

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko Agreed!  This can be a big source of confusion and bugs.  `ng-if` creates a new scope but `ng-show` does not.  This inconsistency has always been a sore spot for me.  The defensive programming reaction to this is: "always bind to something that a dot in the expression" and it won't be an issue.

Comment: If you want to add an attribute that is actually a directive, this works great. Shame about the code duplication

Comment: This worked for me. I was trying to conditionally produce attributes for Bootstrap, and ng-attr would not work for me because Bootstrap finished its processing before Angular did. There may be a way to get Bootstrap to run after Angular, and this solution creates twice as much code, but it works great.

Answer (score 16):

To get an attribute to show a specific value based on a boolean check, or be omitted entirely if the boolean check failed, I used the following:

`ng-attr-example="{{params.type == 'test' ? 'itWasTest' : undefined }}"`

Example usage:

`<div ng-attr-class="{{params.type == 'test' ? 'itWasTest' : undefined }}">`

Would output `<div class="itWasTest">` or `<div>` based on the value of `params.type`

Answer (score 10):

`<h1 ng-attr-contenteditable="{{isTrue || undefined }}">{{content.title}}</h1>`

will produce when isTrue=true :
`<h1 contenteditable="true">{{content.title}}</h1>`

and when isTrue=false :
`<h1>{{content.title}}</h1>`

Comment: what if I want some thing like <h1 contenteditable="row">

Comment: `<h1 ng-attr-contenteditable="{{isTrue ? 'row' : undefined}}">{{content.title}} </h1>`

Comment: This should me be the accepted answer. My scenario was
`<video ng-attr-autoplay="{{vm.autoplay || undefined}}" />`

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the accepted solution, the one posted by Ashley Davis, the method described still prints the attribute in the DOM, regardless of the fact that the value it has been assigned is undefined.

For example, on an input field setup with both an ng-model and a value attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" data-ng-attr-value="{{myValue}}" data-ng-model="myModel" />
```

Regardless of what's behind myValue, the **value** attribute still gets printed in the DOM, thus, interpreted. Ng-model then, becomes overridden.

A bit unpleasant, but using ng-if does the trick:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" data-ng-if="value" data-ng-attr-value="{{myValue}}" data-ng-model="myModel" />
<input type="text" name="myInput" data-ng-if="!value" data-ng-model="myModel" />
```

I would recommend using a more detailed check inside the ng-if directives :)

Comment: With this approach, you will be repeating the same code though.

Comment: True, but it keeps the model declaration safe. My problem with using the accepted solution was that the value attribute ended up in the DOM, taking precedence over the model declaration. So, if the value attribute is empty but the model is not, the model will be overridden to take an empty value.

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use an expression like this:

```
<h1 ng-attr-contenteditable="{{ editMode ? true : false }}"></h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

I actually wrote a patch to do this a few months ago (after someone asked about it in #angularjs on freenode).

It probably won't be merged, but it's very similar to ngClass: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4269

Whether it gets merged or not, the existing ng-attr-* stuff is probably suitable for your needs (as others have mentioned), although it might be a bit clunkier than the more ngClass-style functionality that you're suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

For input field validation you can do:

```
<input ng-model="discount" type="number" ng-attr-max="{{discountType == '%' ? 100 : undefined}}">
```

This will apply the attribute `max` to `100` only if `discountType` is defined as `%`

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*: This answer is related to Angular2+! Sorry, I missed the tag!

*Original answer:*

As for the very simple case when you only want to apply (or set) an attribute if a certain Input value was set, it's as easy as

```
<my-element [conditionalAttr]="optionalValue || false">
```

It's the same as:

```
<my-element [conditionalAttr]="optionalValue ? optionalValue : false">
```

(So optionalValue is applied if given otherwise the expression is false and attribute is not applied.)

Example: I had the case, where I let apply a color but also arbitrary styles, where the color attribute didn't work as it was already set (even if the @Input() color wasn't given):

```
@Component({
  selector: "rb-icon",
  styleUrls: ["icon.component.scss"],
  template: "<span class="ic-{{icon}}" [style.color]="color==color" [ngStyle]="styleObj" ></span>",
})
export class IconComponent {
   @Input() icon: string;
   @Input() color: string;
   @Input() styles: string;

   private styleObj: object;
...
}
```

So, "style.color" was only set, when the color attribute was there, otherwise the color attribute in the "styles" string could be used.

Of course, this could also be achieved with

```
[style.color]="color"
```

and

```
@Input color: (string | boolean) = false;
```

Comment: Angular.JS is Angular 1, which is very different from Angular 2+. Your solution answers for Angular 2+, but AngularJS (1) was asked for.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3: You are right. Sorry I missed that! Thanks. I edited the answer to point that out. :-)

Comment: is angularjs not angular, angularjs is angular 1

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get this working:

```
ng-attr-aria-current="{{::item.isSelected==true ? 'page' : undefined}}"
```

The nice thing here is that if item.isSelected is false then the attribute simply isn't rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need solution for Angular 2 then its simple, use property binding like below, e.g. you want to make input read only conditionally, then add in square braces the attrbute followed by = sign and expression.

```
<input [readonly]="mode=='VIEW'">
```

Comment: is angularjs (angular1) not angular (angular2)

Comment: angular 2+ and Angular JS are not same, they are more like different products altogether.