# Add attribute without value

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on one of my first angular templates. While looping through an array, I would like to add the attribute `required`.

Every itteration of the array looks like this:

```
        {
            label: 'Last Name',
            name: 'lastname',
            key: 'entry.1417082936'
        }
```

I could simply add

```
            {
                label: 'Last Name',
                name: 'lastname',
                key: 'entry.1417082936',
                required: 'required', 
            }
```

and then add `{{required}}` to the template, but i'm wondering wether there is a cleaner way of doing it. I will need to  add the pattern-attribute as well.

If the `requierd: true` is set I want the attribute requierd to be included into the html, to something like this:

`<input required />`

Comment: You may find this useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a Boolean ? This is typically a good case for that !

Comment: What should i put in the template? I only know of ng-if, but that will affect the entire tag.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly in your template ?