# AngularJS conditional attribute

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to get conditional attribute (not class)?

e.g.:

```
<form-field {true: 'required'}[field.required]></form-field>
```

expected results

```
<form-field required></form-field>
```

or

```
<f orm-field ></form-field>
```

now I've got an

> Error: The string contains invalid characters.

This is in html file not in template which I can compile.

Comment: Try using ng-attr-*.  See this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angular).

Comment: It doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. In your case, you can of course use the `ngRequired` parameter of the [`input`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput) directive.

Inspired by this exemple, you can use a similar trick for your custom directives: just add a parameter that indicate whether or not the directive is enabled.

Comment: Yes, but i need it also for more attributes, the required was the simpliest example - but of course you're right

Comment: This is actually completely possible. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form-field required={{field.required}}></form-field>
```

Which resolves to

```
<form-field required=true></form-field>
```

JSFiddle Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9973/

Comment: Your example doesn't work. I think the field is getting set to disable because it simply exists. If you change the $scope.disable variable to false, the field is still disabled.