# When to use ng-attr?

Tags: angularjs

It seems like using direct attributes and the `ng-attr-*` directive do the same thing. For example, the following render equivalently:

```
   <div ng-attr-id="{{ 'object-' + value }}">ID</div>
   <div id="{{ 'object-' + value }}">ID</div>
```

When should I use `ng-attr-*` and when should I use the direct HTML attribute?

Comment: Yes they are the same `ng-attr` is used when the attribute would otherwise be eagerly processed by browsers please read here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (look for "ngAttr attribute bindings")

Answer (score 17):

ng-attr is used for add or not the attribute in context. If the expression `{{undefined || null}}`, the attribute is not added otherwise if has a value then attribute is added with the value `{{ value }}`.
The most common cases is in interpolation.
Related:
[Conditionally adding data-attribute in Angular directive template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049824/conditionally-adding-data-attribute-in-angular-directive-template)

Comment: Subtle but important correction: My testing shows that if the attribute is omitted only if the expression evaluates to `undefined`.  If the expression evaluates to `null`, the attribute will be present but the assigned value will be omitted.  For example: `<input ng-attr-disabled="{{null}}">` would become `<input disabled>`.  This is described in the angularjs documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes).

Answer (score 9):

There are only a few situations where `ng-attr-[attribute]="{{angular stuff}}"` is different from just `[attribute]="{{angular stuff}}"`. Certain elements within certain browsers can be broken if ng-attr is not used. Angular's documentation lists a few examples:

> - **size** in `<select>` elements (see issue 1619)
> - **placeholder** in `<textarea>` in Internet Explorer 10/11 (see issue 5025)
> - **type** in `<button>` in Internet Explorer 11 (see issue 14117)
> - **value** in `<progress>` in Internet Explorer = 11 (see issue 7218)

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes

Comment: This is the only complete and correct answer I see here.

Answer (score 8):

You use them for custom html data attributes - like if you wanted an attribute of let's say myData you would do

```
  <div ng-attr-myData="{{ 'object-' + value }}">ID</div>
```

Comment: OK. What's dif between ng-attr-myData and myData ?

Comment: You cant evaluate myData. Your example only works because it uses ID which already exists. @zloctb

Comment: for camel case attributes you would actually need to do `ng-attr-my_data`, but as @zloctb states this provides no benefit over just setting a myData attribute without `ng-attr-`

Answer (score 0):

**ng-attr** can be used to dynamically assign value to an attribute of any html element.

One case, where I used it was to associate a label to a form control with dynamic id.

```
<label ng-attr-for="{{parameter.name}}">{{ parameter.name }}</label>
<input ng-attr-id="{{parameter.name}}" type="text">
```

Also, it can be used to assign dynamic value to a custom attribute.
Reference: [here](https://codehumsafar.wordpress.com/2018/08/10/assign-dynamic-id-in-angular-js/)