# In angular, how can I use ng-if for the containing tag only without the trailing markup

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Let's say I have two HTML elements with the same tag, but each with a different set of properties. How can I conditionally choose between them?

I have the following two tags:

```
<a ui-sref="root.one(::{param: value})">
<a target="_blank" href="{{::model}}">
```

I need to conditionally choose one of them, and add other markup until the closing tag.
Can something like this work?

```
<a ng-if="::condition" ui-sref="root.one(::{param: value})">
<a ng-else target="_blank" href="{{::model}}">
  <div>
    more nodes
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Instead of using the `href` attribute, use angular's `ngHref` like this: `<a ng-href="::{{ condition ? 'http://trueCondition,com' : 'http://falseCondition.com' }}"  ng-attr-target="::{{ condition ? '_blank' : '_self' }}"  ....>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally adding data-attribute in Angular directive template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049824/conditionally-adding-data-attribute-in-angular-directive-template)

Comment: The anchor tag itself doesn't matter. It could be on any tag, with any property.

Comment: I'll edit the question with a better example

Comment: @NirD. There's no such thing as `ng-else` if the condition inside the `ngIf` evaluated as **true** then the element will be visible in the DOM, otherwise it is removed from the DOM (Unlike `ngHide` / `ngShow` that just make it visible or invisible, based on the condition). 
You can either use [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) or a directive and bind it to and  `A` element, and avoid duplicate of the markup

Answer (score 0):

At the end I figured this to be impossible, so I resorted to merging the A tags like this:

```
<a ng-attr-target="{{::!condition? '_blank' : undefined}}" href="{{::model}}" ng-attr-ui-sref="{{::(condition? 'root.one(::{param: value})' : '.')}}">
```

Remarks:

1. When the condition is met, ng-attr-target expression is set to undefined so that the target attribute will not be inserted at all. Apparently, if you set it to _self it messes up angular routing
2. When the condition is not met, ng-attr-ui-sref expression is set to some random undeclared ui-sref route - '.'. Usually you would just set it to undefined if you don't want the attribute to be inserted, but there's some bug in ui-sref or in angular, that results in some errors in the console so I had to resort to this method.