# AngularJS - Insert variable to script attribute

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a variable "widgetDataHash" (string) and script tag like this:

```
<script 
   type="text/javascript" 
   id="widget"
   data-hash="{{widgetDataHash}}"
   src="www.widgetsrc.com">
</script>
```

I want to insert value of `widgetDataHash` to `data-hash` attribute like that. But when it run, it just show a normal text `{{widgetDataHash}}` instead of value of `widgetDataHash`.

Any solution for this ?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write like this `[attr.data-hash]="widgetDataHash"` for angular 2+ and for Angularjs you should write like this 
`ng-attr-data-hash="widgetDataHash"`
I should mention that I found this solution (for Angularjs solution) in a link Nobita answered that. For more information check [Conditionally adding data-attribute in Angular directive template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049824/conditionally-adding-data-attribute-in-angular-directive-template) answers

Comment: thats for angular 2+

Comment: Thank you for notice. I changed my answer.

Comment: It just work with normal tag html except script. Do you have any another idea ?