# Conditionally adding an element attribute in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

How can I add specific attribute to the element based on the Boolean value?

```
<video ng-attr="{autoplay:is_autoplay}">
    ...
```

Comment: The accepted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angular) question should be useful.

Comment: can you write specific code? I used following snippet but didn't work. <video ng-attr-autoplay="{{is_autoplay}}">

Comment: ng-attr-class never made it into 1.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [conditionally add an element attribute in angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136040/conditionally-add-an-element-attribute-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like angular lets you set attributes currently (ng-attr-class doesn't tend to work). A slightly redundant workaround would be to do this:

```
<video autoplay ng-if="is_autoplay">
<video ng-if="!is_autoplay">
```