# conditionally add an element attribute in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add an autoplay attribute to a video tag based on the is_autoplay scope variable.

I searched all over the internet, but I couldn't find the exact snippet I wanted.

I tried following but none of them work.

---

```
<video autoplay="{{is_autoplay ? 'true' : 'false'}}">
    ...
```

---

```
<video ng-attr-autoplay="{is_autoplay}">
    ...
```

---

Someone even suggested the following

```
<video {{is_autoplay ? "autoplay" : ""}}>
    ...
```

---

---

The following solved my problem.

```
app.directive('attronoff', function() {
    return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.$watch(
            function () { return $element.attr('data-attr-on'); },
            function (newVal) { 
                var attr = $element.attr('data-attr-name');

                if(!eval(newVal)) {
                    $element.removeAttr(attr);
                }
                else {
                    $element.attr(attr, attr);
                }
            }
        );
        }
    };
});
```

Anyone can use this directive to add/remove attribute conditionally.

`Usage`

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls attronoff data-attr-on="{{is_autoplay}}" data-attr-name="autoplay">
    ...
```

Comment: I know it is late, but can be useful. For angular 1.3+ and attribute without values (e.g. autoplay or required) you can use 'undefined': `<video ng-attr-autoplay="is_autoplay || undefined">...</video>`. It’s removed because ng-attr- has the allOrNothing feature of removing an attribute if the expression yields undefined.

Answer (score 6):

One Simple solution would be to use `ng-if` to generate the dom based on the condition.

For instance in your case, use

```
<video autoplay="true" ng-if="is_autoplay">...</video>
<video ng-if="!is_autoplay">...</video>
```

So if `is_autoplay` is `true`, the first element will be generated with the `autoplay` attribute and second on will not be in dom.

If `is_autoplay` is `false`, the second dom element will be generated without the `autoplay` attribue.

Comment: thanks. I know this would work, but this method is not always a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly set the autoplay attribute based on your is_autoplay property:

```
<video autoplay="{{is_autoplay}}">...</video>
```

Comment: "The autoplay attribute is a boolean attribute.When present, the audio will automatically start playing as soon as it can do so without stopping."