# Dynamic attribute with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to add lang='fa' attribute to all input:text in my form with angular .

with a little condition : if body has class `fa` all `input:text` **not email type** get lang="fa" attribute .

i know how to do it with jquery but i don't know how to do it in angular way .
here is my fiddle with Jquery : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eh176tLg/)
**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($("body").hasClass('fa')){
            if('input:text'){
                $('input:text').attr('lang','fa');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you have to write your own directive

Comment: ok,but where should i add the custom directive ? in body ?

Comment: Or you can still use jQuery because jQuery works well with AngularJS. AngularJS is a framework and jQuery is a liblary, if you can do something easier in jQuery than in Angular just do it :)

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angular

Comment: thank you guys, i get the answer . @szapio that's not the best way to use jquery in angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add functionality to the `input` directive (or any directive). This is simply done by declaring it once again. The following will do what you want:

```
// we assume that the var isFa is already set, e.g as:
var isFa = angular.element(document.body).hasClass('fa');

app.directive('input', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            if( isFa && elem.attr('type') === 'text' ) {
                elem.attr('lang','fa');
            }
        }
    };
});
```

No need for jQuery. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b37wdm07/