# How to set ng-attr-title using ternary operator in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to Angularjs. I want to set a value for **title** attribute, based on a boolean variable.

Sample code attached here.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="doc in $data" ng-class="{{doc.is_today}} ? 'highlight' : ''" 
                                        ng-attr-title="({{doc.is_today}}) ? 'Today' : ''"> 
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angular

Comment: @Shershen thanks for your reply, find a solution 

    <tr ng-repeat="doc in $data" ng-class="{{doc.is_today}} ? 'highlight' : ''" 
        ng-attr-title="{{doc.is_today == 1 && 'Today' || ''}}"> 
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
    </tr>

Comment: yes, that's exactly what you should use: {{ condition && 'A' || 'B'}}

Answer (score 4):

Remove {{}} in condition

```
<tr ng-repeat="doc in $data" ng-class="doc.is_today ? 'highlight' : ''" 
                                        ng-attr-title="doc.is_today ? 'Today' : ''"> 
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

Only use {{}} if you want to print the value.

Alternatively you can do the following also

```
<tr ng-repeat="doc in $data" ng-class="{{doc.is_today ? 'highlight' : ''}}" 
                                            ng-attr-title="{{doc.is_today ? 'Today' : ''}}"> 
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>5</td>
    </tr>
```

Link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/gaxhjmhj/)

Comment: Check the link in the answer.

Comment: thanks Aakash. class is not a problem. the problem is assign a value to title attribute. but fixed that issue. thanks for your are time.

Comment: And where is attr-title in jsfiddle?