# Add attributeif ng-if is false. angular

Tags: angularjs, attr

Im new with Angular JS

And im trying to add an attribute to a table if an ng-if is false,

I want to add a "ui:sortable" if my function "onlyRead()" is false.

How can I do it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can look into `ng-attr` with an expression. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angular) is an SO post on `ng-attr`.

Comment: It would be more easy to answer your question if you show us the valid pieces of your code..

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, here an example. http://jsfiddle.net/vz6b13zn/1/

I'm just trying to add ui:sortable to the tbody when OnlyRead is false