# Javascript: How do I add an HTML code within tags after a given condition is found to be true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I cannot use ng-if because if the condition is false, it would remove the whole tag(will it?), which I don't want. I just want a small code to be added within tags if condition is true, and not-added if it is false.

I have something like:

```
<input ***stuff*** ng-if="condition==true" style="text-transform:capitalize"/>
```

If the condition is true, simply add the style in the tag, otherwise, don't add it.
I know I can do it by adding a class if the condition is met true and then add the css-part for the class, but, is it possible the way I've mentioned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to conditionally apply attributes in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ng-style you can achieve your result:

Here is an example.

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.condition = true;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-style="condition ? {'text-transform': 'capitalize'} : ''"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [ng class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<input ***stuff*** ng-class="{'capitalize': condition}" />
```

With css:

```
.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: @Vineet are the single quotes necessary? The angular documentation doesn't use them. It's been awhile since I've used ng-class myself.

Comment: Yes you can use in either ways.