# draggable true not working in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div:

```
  <div draggable = "true" ng-show="showPullDown" class="topPull stretch" draggable >

</div>
```

But `draggable =true` is not working. I have tried setting it through controller as well but no help. Any alternatives or fix?

directive:

```
.directive('draggable', function ($ionicGesture) {
  return function(scope, element) {
        // this gives us the native JS object
       var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
        element.draggable=true;
        var el = element[0];
        element.css({
       position: 'relative',
       cursor: 'pointer'
      });

$ionicGesture.on('dragstart',  function(e) { 
         e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';

                return false;
            }, element);


$ionicGesture.on('dragend',  function(e) { 
                return false;
            }, element);
   }
})
```

I get an error..

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'effectAllowed' of undefined

**Also**, `console.log(e)` gives the event but `console.log(e.dataTransfer)` gives `undefined`.

Comment: `element.draggable=true;` and `var el = element[0];` look very suspicious... you're trying to set a property on an array, then selecting the first element out of the array.

Comment: I removed the array thing and have set it to the element alone i.e element.draggable=true. But still the same issue

Comment: when you take out the first element, you need to then wrap that in `angular.element` before you start to access it like jQuery. so in my mind `element.css` wouldn't work but `angular.element(el).css` would...

Comment: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5qOniLuEZOL96uUpbYZL?p=preview) to demonstrate

Comment: But my major concern is to make it draggable which is not happening

Comment: Absolutely, but if everything else works then you can start to narrow down the issue

Comment: Evrything else does. I am able to apply the css and stuff but not really able to make it draggable

Comment: Do you know about this [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-adds-event-listeners)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Angular 1.

```
<div ng-attr-draggable="{{condition || undefined}}">
```

found the hint from the answers posted in the following question.

[What is the best way to conditionally apply attributes in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angularjs)