# Set value dynamically in inline using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I have a repeat loop in which

```
<div draggable="true" ng-repeat="item in items>
    <span>{{item.Id}}</span>
    <span>{{item.des}}</div>
</div>
```

What i want to do is that if item.valid=0 i want to set draggable value to false, else it stays true. 
I was looking into ng-switch but it didnt work fine.
Please let me know how to set draggable value to true or false depending upon the item.valid value. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You want to set the outer element's draggable state based on a repeating value? How do you determine which value overwrites the state?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16669790/3951400

Comment: What I mean is for each item.valid value if it is 0 draggable should be set to False if item.valid is 1 then draggable should be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this if you want to set draggable for each item.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-attr-draggable="{{item.valid == 1 ? 'true' : 'false' }}">
        <span>{{item.Id}}</span>
        <span>{{item.des}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i understand OP correctly - he wants it to be true for every thing except 0, not just if it is 1. `{{item.valid > 0 ? 'true' : 'false' }}` is probably what he needs. good answer though, i learned something new ;)

Comment: @HolyMoly Yeah you might be right. We'll see when OP comments.

Comment: in fact artm, if you could take a peek at the question i just posted, that would be awesome. i'm super stuck :(  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712042/how-do-i-create-menu-items-that-i-can-swap-out-depending-on-page-login-status

Comment: @HolyMoly Everything else then 0 is `item.valid !== 0` ;)