# Unmask Password to plain text and again mask it upon clicking a checkbox

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, html, model-view-controller

I have a password type input element in html5 as follows in my angular mvc based app.

I am having a requirement to have a checkbox near to this, and when the user clicks on the chekcbox, we display the masked password text as plain text in the same password input type textbox which is below code. And again, when the user deselect the checkbox, we should mask the plain text to mask :) Looks like it is simple, I am new here, could someone please help me with possible code

```
 <input type="password" name="password"
                               ng-model="model.password"
                               placeholder="Please type your password">
```

Comment: `$('#c').click(function () { if ($(this).is(':checked')) { $('#p').attr('type', 'text'); } else { $('#p').attr('type', 'password'); } })` where the ckeckbox has `id="c"` and the textbox has `id="p"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `ng-show` or `ng-if` directive for your case.

By the following snippet the input with different type will toggle on the dom.

```
<input type="password" name="password"
                               ng-model="model.password"
                               placeholder="Please type your password"
                               ng-show="!showPassword">

<input type="text" name="password"
                               ng-model="model.password"
                               ng-show="showPassword">

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showPassword">
```

Working [**Fiddle**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jsalaat/dzm9omt7/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: What about `ng-attr-type="{{showPassword && 'text' || 'password' }}"`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16669790/1808494

Comment: Thank you, yours seems very less code achieving the result

Comment: It works, but I can not see the checkbox. I added a label and upon clicking on label it does the job,  <label for="showPassword">Check password</label> But checkbox is invisible, why

Comment: Maybe because of some css issue i guess. Can you provide me a fiddle with the invisible checkbox so could help you. You can change the fiddle I have provided with this answer and send me the new forked link.

Comment: oh yes webkit-appearance in csss is causing this, I am working on it and let you know if I can resolve

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="{{inputType}}" placeholder="Put your password" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" ng-model="pass_cb" ng-click="togglePassword()" />
  <label for="checkbox" ng-if="pass_cb === true">Hide password</label>
  <label for="checkbox" ng-if="pass_cb === false">Show password</label>  
</section>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function( $scope ){

  $scope.pass_cb = false;
  $scope.inputType = 'password';

  $scope.togglePassword = function(){
    if ($scope.inputType == 'password')
      $scope.inputType = 'text';
    else
      $scope.inputType = 'password';
  };
}]);
```

See this Fiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/7278/