# Angular - Add Attribute Based on Window Width

Tags: angularjs

I found some answers to this already - tried them however none of them work for me.

I have the following div where I use the attribute `equalizer`:

`<div class="text-center" equalizer='group'>`

However I only want that attribute `equalizer` to exist if the window width is > 400.

So I also use this code in my controller:

```
$scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;

$window.onresize = function(event) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;
        });
};
```

Now I understand I can do something like:

`equalizer="{{ windowWidth>400 ? 'group' : ''}}"`

However the problem is whether or not I have a value in `equalizer` it is still applied - namely `<div class="text-center" equalizer=''>` works in the same as `<div class="text-center" equalizer='group'>`

So how do completely control whether that attribute is inserted or not?

*TO ADD*
The only solution i have is duplicating the code and the using `ng-if`

so :

`<div ng-if="windowWidth<400" class="text-centre">`

and

`<div ng-if="windowWidth>=400" class="text-center" equalizer='group'>`

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to conditionally apply attributes in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angular)

Comment: @Casey not a duplicate - I have seen that answer: `ng-attr-class="{{someBoolean && 'class-when-true' || 'class-when-false' }}"` however my issue is I need to able to say `equalizer="group"` or not have it at all.

Comment: Why can't you just adjust what `equalizer` directive does internally? Also why not create `$scope.equalizer` and move the ternary to controller?

Comment: @userMod2 So use `ng-attr-equalizer`

Comment: That div can either be `<div>` or `<div equalizer='group'>` - if I use `ng-attr-equalizer="{{windowWidth>400 && 'group'}}"` - then equalizer always appears either with `'group'` or as `''`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a resize directive that's updating a scope variable that you can check inside of your equalizer directive.

I'm not exactly sure what your equalizer directive is doing but something like in the demo below (or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/djqqxhra/)) should work.

In the demo I'm removing the equalizer directive for testing if the resize event is removed with the directive.

Adding a directive would look like the untested code below but I would do it like in the demo with `ng-if`:

```
var childScope = $scope.$new();
var directiveElement = angular.element('<equalizer></equalizer>');
$document.append($compile(directiveElement)(childScope));
```

([Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ftfish/KyEr3/) is a demo found with Google for adding directives dynamically.)

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', function($scope) {
        $scope.equalizerOptions = {
            group: true
        };
        $scope.removeEqualizer = function() {
            // just for testing if resize handler is removed
            var equalizer = angular.element(document).find('equalizer');
            //console.log(angular.element(document).find('equalizer').scope());
            equalizer.scope().$destroy();
            equalizer.remove();
        }
    })
    .directive('equalizer', equalizerDir)
    .directive('resize', resizeDir);

function resizeDir($window) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.window = {};

            function onResize(event) {
                //console.log('Resized', scope, element, event);
                scope.window.width = $window.innerWidth;
            }

            $window.onresize = function(evt) {
                //console.log('Resize');
                scope.$apply(onResize);
            };

            onResize(); //initial call

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                //console.log('destroy dir');
                $window.onresize = undefined;
            });
        }
    };
}

function equalizerDir($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            options: '=',
            width: '@'
        },
        template: '<div ng-if="width >= 400"><h2>equalizer with ng-if & resize dir</h2>' +
            '<p>{{options.group ? \'grouped\': \'not grouped\'}}</p></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            /*scope.$watchCollection('options', function() {
             // would work but watch with ternary operator directly in markup is easier
             scope.text = scope.options.group ? 'grouped': 'not grouped';  
            });*/
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  window width debugging: {{window.width}}
  <equalizer options="equalizerOptions" width="{{window.width}}" resize>
  </equalizer>

  <button ng-click="equalizerOptions.group = !equalizerOptions.group">
    toggle group
  </button>
  <button ng-click="removeEqualizer()">
    remove equalizer (test unbinding resize)
  </button>
</div>
```