# How to add conditional add html attribute?

Tags: angularjs

How to add conditionally attribute in angularjs?

For example I only want to set the `multiple` attribute on a `<select>` if my component has a binding set to true. This means if the binding is not given the multiple attribute should not exist on my `<select>`.

The only solution I found was with ng-if.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to conditionally apply attributes in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angular)

Comment: use ng-if, ng-show ...

Comment: do you tried with multiple="{{ yourVar}}" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by implementing a directive (aka `ng-multiple`) to handle the property `multiple` of the `select` element. The following snippet implements this solution. However, you may want to control the state of your model inside this `directive`, once the `multiple` prop will produce an array of selected values, the `non-multiple` will produce a single object, so this may cause an issue when switching between `multiple` and `non-multiple`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('ngMultiple', function () {
    return {
      require: ['select', '?ngModel'],
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        multiple: '=ngMultiple'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
        
        element.prop('multiple', scope.multiple);
        
        scope.$watch('multiple', function (multiple) {
          if(element.prop('multiple') != multiple){
            // may be would be convenient change the ngModel
            // to [] or {} depending on the scenario
            element.prop('multiple', multiple);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.condition = true;
    $scope.myOptions = [];
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="condition" /> multiple?
  </label>
  <br>
  <select ng-multiple="condition" ng-model="myOptions">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <tt>myOptions: {{ myOptions }}</tt>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if boolean `condition` is true then multiple, else not

```
<select ng-if="condition" ng-model="some.model" multiple></select>
<select ng-if="!condition" ng-model="some.model"></select>


<select ng-show="condition" ng-model="some.model" multiple></select>
<select ng-hide="condition" ng-model="some.model"></select>
```

controller,

`$scope.condition = true`