# Why 'ng-attr-' can't be used with attribute 'multiple'?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to make a `<select>` behave with single or multiple selection depending on a condition. So far I have tried:

```
<select  
ng-model="data.model"
ng-attr-multiple="{{myCondition ? '' : undefined}}">
```

(here's a plnkr I have been testing with https://plnkr.co/edit/ACKBMZSJc2MVSJaDBGMY?p=preview)
But it won't work. Even leaving ng-attr-multiple alone won't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: May be helpful: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6950#issuecomment-89730346

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/selmulti

> Binding to the multiple attribute of select element is not supported
>   since switching between multiple and single mode changes the ngModel
>   object type from instance to array of instances which breaks the model
>   semantics.
>
> If you need to use different types of select elements in your template
>   based on some variable, please use ngIf or ngSwitch directives to
>   select one of them to be used at runtime.

Comment: Very well explained. This is what I was looking for. I guess there's no other way than using `<select ng-if="multipleCondition" multiple>` or a switch.

Comment: Thanks mate, this was driving me nuts!