# Angular js ng-if conditons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a html , ng-if start work with multiple tag , i want to apply within attributes

```
    <td class="text-right" ng-if-start="hascancelData" rowspan="2" ng-if-end>
     <strong>{{cancelData.refundAmount | currency}}</strong>
    </td>
```

I have to apply rowspan="2" only when hascancelData:true. I have tried ^^

Comment: You can't do that, You can try `rowspan="{{hascancelData ? 2 : ''}}"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to conditionally apply attributes in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angular)

Comment: No it is not duplicate ng-if start work with multiple tags , i want to apply within attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td class="text-right" ng-if="hascancelData" rowspan="{{hascancelData}}?'2':''">
     <strong>{{cancelData.refundAmount | currency}}</strong>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<td class="text-right" ng-if-start="hascancelData" rowspan="{{hascancelData ? 2 : ''}}" ng-if-end>
```