# How to add conditional click attribute to link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make an anchor tag trigger a function if a particular variable is set. In the example below `name` is set to `"Shnick"` and so the link when clicked should trigger the `func()` method. However, nothing happens when I click the link.

If the `name` is not set, then I do not want the `click` attribute to appear and so the `func()` method won't execute.

I have tried looking at these two answers on adding conditional attributes in Angular:

- [How to add conditional attribute in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2)
- [What is the best way to conditionally apply attributes in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angularjs)

But none of those have worked. Here are my attempts at using the two answers presented above

Attempt #1:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Shnick";
    $scope.func = function() {
      alert("Link Clicked!");
    };
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <p>Name: {{ name }} </p>
  <a href="#" [attr.click]="name ? func() : null">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Attempt #2:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Shnick";
    $scope.func = function() {
      alert("Link Clicked!");
    };
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <p>Name: {{ name }} </p>
  <a href="#" ng-attr-click="name ? func() : undefined">Click me</a>
</div>
```

So, how can I conditionally add the `click` attribute such that it is only added when `name` is set and will execute the `func()` method when clicked?

Comment: I'd recommend not changing the link, but put some logic in the function instead, and let that logic determine what to do.  It's much easier and makes the markup tidier and easier to follow.

Comment: I would recomend creating a new function of the form `function onAnchorClick(){if (this.name) this.func(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to overcomplicate things with ternary conditions, add this checking logic inside the function itself, something like this should work:

```
$scope.func = function() {
  if(!$scope.name) {
    return;
  }
  alert("Link Clicked!");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Code:**

```
<a ng-href='{{link}}' ng-click='test(type);'> your link </a>
```

**js code:**

```
$scope.name = "";
$scope.$watch('m', function(value){
    ($scope.name = "Shnick") ? ($scope.link = 'actual_link') : ($scope.link = '');
})
```

Comment: There is no need of watcher. This is a bad practice