# How in angular 1 depending on scope can I add e-required attribute?

Tags: angularjs

How in angular 1 depending on scope can I add e-required attribute?
Doesn't want to use ng-show

E.g. for $scope.disableStreetValidation = false;

```
 <strong class="test" e-required>.
```

And for:
$scope.disableStreetValidation = true;

```
  <strong class="test">.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696416/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-attributes-in-angularjs), you should use this syntaks:

```
 <strong class="test" ng-attr-e-required="{{disableStreetValidation || undefined}}">
```